# MS Access 2007 - Select data from Database C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2007

Good Morning all, i have a problem when display data from my mdb database.

My Code :

```
    private void btn_Preview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM DATA where tgl BETWEEN #01/01/2017# AND #30/01/2017# order by tgl  Asc";
        //string sql = "SELECT * FROM DATA where tgl = #07/01/2017#";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "DATA");
        conn.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["DATA"].DefaultView;


    }
```

when i run the program

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM DATA where tgl BETWEEN #01/01/2017# AND #30/01/2017# order by tgl  Asc";
```

this is the result: Result when use show Between date

[image: Result when use show Between date]

then i try to run with specific date :

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM DATA where tgl = #07/01/2017#";
```

[image: Using specific date]

no record appear.

when i change #07/01/2017# to #29/12/2016# the data is loaded to Datagridview1

Please tell me what wrong with my code.
when i use #07/01/2017# the data can't loaded to datagridview, but when i use date between 01/01/2017 and 30/01/2017 the data is loaded and contain 07/01/2017.

Thanks

Comment: Check your date format. try both 01/07/2017 and 07/01/2017

Comment: thanks alot, finaly it's work :)

I so confused, when i use 29/12/2016 it's work too. Then i assume the format is dd/MM/yyyy. I convert the datetimepicker1 to dd/MM/yyyy format.

Answer (score 0):

Check the date format, it is the most probable cause of this irregularity. Try 01/07/2017 instead. You can also change the date format in control panel -> clock language, and region, so you can have the date/time format of your choice.